# jQuery AJAX post callback doesn't seems to work

Tags: ajax, jquery, post

I did this lots of times:

```
var url = '/offers/1/voting';
var params = { 'direction': 'up' };
$.post(url, params, function() {
  alert('callback');
}); // post
```

(I'm hardcoding the values for this example, but nothing)

So, through firebug I receive the desired JSON response (200 status), but **the callback doesn't execute**. It's pretty much the only javascript I'm using. Tried with jquery 1.6.4 and 1.7.1 and it's the same thing with both. I don't know what I'm missing.

Help me, Stack Overflow. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use $.ajax instead of $.post ($.post is really an overwrite of $.ajax with fewer parameters), you can add a handler for error and see if it fires:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/offers/1/voting',
        data:  { 'direction': 'up' },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) 
                { alert('success') },
        error: function (err)
        { alert(err.responseText)}
    });
```

Comment: It fired the error callback with my response. I thought that the error callback fired when response code != 200, but I must be wrong. So, probably I'm doing something wrong in my controller. Now I have to check that out. Thank you Andrey!

Comment: If you don't return any data in the response to the POST request, then the jquery JSON parser fails to parse the empty response (empty is not valid JSON) and returns an error despite the 200 OK.  Note the dataType parameter is for the format of the data returned from the server according to the documentation for $.post and NOT the format of the data passed to the server.  If you know the response is empty then change dataType to "text" and you should see your success handler fire.

Comment: I would expand on @SteveGrove's comment - it's not just empty response, but any non-JSON response. Say, if you post a vote and it returns a new number of votes as just a number, then jQuery will fail to parse that into JSON and jQuery will throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

try this

> `$.post(url, params, function(callback) { alert(callback); });`

Comment: do you get alert at all? or are you getting a blank alert?

Comment: It was an error response, I must study it yet. See Andrey response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8314969/319241